# ANDROID_NDK--path not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have installed Android NDK.I have to compile an application natively.

```
ara@Aravind:~/Downloads/adrenosdk-linux/Development/Samples/OpenCLVectorAdd/Android/jni$ ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build
```

I am getting the error::::
bash: ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build: No such file or directory

My Path Variable is pointing to the android-ndk-r10c and I have made this path permanent.
What is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$ANDROID_NDK` in the instructions is a placeholder meant to be replaced with the path to your NDK directory. If that directory is already in your path, you should only have to type `ndk-build`.

Comment: Thanks Dan.It is compiling.I m getting errors.                                       /home/ara/Downloads/adrenosdk-linux/Development/Samples/OpenCL/VectorAdd/Android/jni/../../../../Framework/OpenCL/FrmKernel.cpp:42: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateProgramWithSource'. Can u plse help?

Comment: Are you linking opencl?

Comment: Yes I am. I hv OpenCL compatibile device. Also i compiled OpenGL sample.It worked.Thanks. So problem is with OpenCL?

Comment: Not sure. You'll have to post your Android.mk. Also, you should select this answer as the right one since it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan.Ya surely I will. here is my Android.mk Plse c if u can help.                                                                                                              # Copyright (c) 2013 QUALCOMM Technologies, Inc.
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
SRC_PATH   := ../..

CL_TEST_CHECK := true
SDK_SAMPLE_NAME := VectorAdd
include $(SRC_PATH)/../Android_common.mk

Comment: Edit your post (or ask a new question since it is a new question). Comments don't preserve formatting.